# Next textbox disable in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I want to add one validation like if Status is "Accept" then QtyRejected get disable 
[image]
Below is my ASP code for status and qtyRejected

```
<td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lAccept" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="102px">
                            <asp:ListItem>Accept</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Reject</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>

                    </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td width="30%">
                        <b>Qty Rejected:</b> 
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="lRejectedQty" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                      <%--  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                            ErrorMessage="Only interger between 1 to 10000000 " ondisposed="Page_Load" 
                            oninit="Page_Load" onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>--%>

                    </td>   

                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (lAccept.SelectedItem.Text == "Accept")
        {
            lRejectedQty.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this work g8t.. only thing we have to take care make AutoPostBack="True" for the status.Thanks @irishChieftain

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the selected value of the dropdownlist using jQuery with something like this.

```
$('#<%= lAccept.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
```

Then you can disable your textbox with a little more jQuery with something like this.

```
$('#<%=lRejectedQty.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

And if you want to re-enable.

```
$('#<%=lRejectedQty.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries as long as you figured it out. Cheers!